# Conexión bidireccional entre dos maquinas con SSH autentificada con clave publica rsa

Tags: linux, ssh

Tengo 2 raspberry en cada una un user jorge con privilegios root con pass digamos "jorge" tambien, y mi intencion es poder hacer ssh al user jorge de una maquina a otra sin pass, ejemplo `ssh -p22 jorge@192.168.200.4 y ssh -p22 jorge@192.168.200.3` respectivamente.

Digamos que una es A y otra es B , en A ejecute `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` `ssh-copy-id jorge@192.168.200.4` (tambien probe a copiar la .pub a B y hacer `cat $HOME/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`, pero tampco me habia servido) , bueno con el copy introduci la pass y posteriormente en la otra maquina (B) pues probe a hacer `ssh -i /root/.ssh/authorized_keys -p22 root@192.168.200.3`o mismamente ssh normal y cree el fingerpint meti la pass, pero claro desde B a A(en la que se genero  el par de claves) siempre pide pass.

Bueno tmb probe a validar los hosts `ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.200.3 >/root/.ssh/known_hosts` pero nada.

Alguna sugerencia?, se que este post no es de programación sino de administración de sistemas, pero no se donde formular esta pregunta sino es aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a suponer que el comando `ssh-copy-id` en ambos dispositivos te ha funcionado correctamente.

En este caso y seun información dada, el comando `-i`  de `ssh -i /root/.ssh/authorized_keys -p22 root@192.168.200.3`  no es correcto.

`-i` se trata del fichero de identificación donde se encuentra la **llave privada**  *(pausa)*  de la **publica compartida**.

`authorized_keys`es donde se pegan las llaves publicas que estan authorizadas.

En tu caso no te funciona ya que `-i authorized_keys` no es  el fichero de la llave privada de la relación.

Por defecto, si la llaves es alguna de esas:

- ~/.ssh/id_dsa,
- ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
- ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk,
- ~/.ssh/id_ed25519,
- ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

> Información en manual de ssh -> `man ssh`

El sistema por defecto ya las inlcuye como `identity files`.  Si te interesa, tambien puedes configurar en el fichero `ssh_config` eses `identity files`de modo global

#### verificacion de las llaves intercambiadas

1. En A  `cat .ssh/nombrellave.pub` debe estar en B y lo miras con `cat ./ssh/authorized_keys`
2. En B  `cat .ssh/nombrellave.pub` debe estar en A y lo miras con `cat ./ssh/authorized_keys`

#### otros

- El puerto ssh por defecto es `22` asi que puedes estalviartelo cuanto quieras conectar a una maquina con el `cliente ssh` :  ssh -i .ssh/llave.privada  root@192.168.200.3
- Recuerda siempre que la configuracion especifica por usuario esta dentro de `.ssh/` del directorio del usuario en `home` o en `root`en caso de ser `root`.